# How does RegExp.exec Populate Its Results Array

Tags: regex, proof-general

I'm playing with a some regular expressions and, while looking at some of my matches, I became curious as to why a the exec function produced as many results as it did.

I'm simply seeking a little clarification on the inner workings of the operation so that I can feel more comfortable with *why* a regular expression is returning *n* results, instead of just accepting that it does.

Ex.

```
var invalidValues = new RegExp(
"\\bZIP or City & State$|" +
"\\bCity & State or ZIP$|" +
"\\bEm[ai][ia]l Address(\\s\\(Optional\\)|$)|" +
"^$", "gi"); 

invalidValues.exec("Zip or City & State");
//returns ["Zip or City & State", undefined]
```

In the example above, I get why it's matching "Zip or City & State", but I don't know why a second match is being produced with an undefined value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Proof General, but it looks as though `exec` returns only a *single* match at a time. The results that you're seeing are:

- `"Zip or City & State"` — the complete matched substring.
- `undefined` — the substring captured by the `(\\s\\(Optional\\)|$)` [capture-group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Or *not* captured, in this case, because that capture-group is inside a non-matching alternand.

To remove the latter, you can (presumably) change the `(` to `(?:`, marking it as a non-capturing group.

To retrieve subsequent matches, you likely need to call `exec` multiple times.